# Post value fail while checked the checkboxes using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter-3

I tried to post values while checked the checkbox using ajax, but it fail, the code seems right to me.. on the url it's appear like this, that it shouldn't..

```
http://localhost/logsys/admin/roleaccess/%3C?%20$role[%27id%27];%20?%3E
```

I'm using codeigniter v 3.1.10, running on xampp v 7.3.0

```
<script>
    $('.form-check-input').on('click', function() {
        const menuId = $(this).data('menu');
        const roleId = $(this).data('role');

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?= base_url('admin/changeaccess'); ?>",
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                menuId: menuId,
                roleId: roleId

            },
            success: function() {
                document.location.href = "<?= base_url('admin/roleaccess/'); ?>" + roleId;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

It should pass the value that allows user get access for some menu

Comment: That's coming from `+ roleId` at the end. What's the value of `roleId`?

Comment: it is an integer value from database to recognize user role, whether it is an administrator or user... thanks, it solved now..

Comment: It's supposed to be an integer, but obviously it isn't. The value is the literal string `<? $role['id']; ?>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    $('.form-check-input').on('click', function() {
        const menuId = $(this).data('menu');
        const roleId = $(this).data('role'); // roleId = <? $role[‘id’] ?> so php did not echo role id here

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?= base_url('admin/changeaccess'); ?>",
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                menuId: menuId,
                roleId: roleId

            },
            success: function() {
                document.location.href = "<?= base_url('admin/roleaccess/'); ?>" + roleId;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

For solution change your `form-check-input` element

```
<... class=“form-check-input” data-role=“<?php echo $role[‘id’]; ?>” data-menu=“echo menu variable” ...>
```

If this doesn’t work to share your html of `form-check-input` button

Comment: thanks bro,  I wrote php echo like this <?= $role['id']?>, but I missed "=".. your answer remind me that !